# Is it possible to use the output of recurse_subfolders to train BagOfFeatures network?

Tags: matlab, function, machine-learning, classification

I have imported the folder and subfolders to the workspace of matlab using `recurse_subfolder` function, but I want use it to train the `BagOfVisualWords`.

I was trying the `setDir` function to import my folder and subfolders but it was not working, therefore I now imported the files using `recurse_subfolder`. How can I use its output to train `BagOfFeatures`? Thank you.

Comment: Please, provide a code example illustrating the problem you are having. Including the backtrace of errors would help too.

Comment: @Nick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60810895/is-it-possible-to-use-the-output-of-recurse-subfolders-to-train-bagoffeatures-ne

Comment: @Nick Error message: Undefined function 'splitEachLabel' for input arguments of type 'double'.
Error in visual (line 79)
[trainingSet, validationSet] = splitEachLabel(numberOfImageFiles, 0.7, 'randomize');